# Didn't understand relationship 'Orders' in FROM part of query call

Tags: soql, relationships, childrelationship

I have a problem to attempt to the Order object based on the custom Contact lookup.
I use the query:

```
select Id, (select id from Orders ) from Contact
```

and the object looks like that:
[image]

The error is:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Orders' in FROM part of query call.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a custom relationship between `Contact` and `Orders`, you will have to use `__r` with the child relationship name.

So your query should be

```
select Id, (select id from Orders__r) from Contact
```

You can get further information about the custom relationship name and how to use parent to child relationship queries at this salesforce documentation [Understanding Relationship Names, Custom Objects, and Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm)

Comment: +1. Good explain.

Comment: Hi @Quicki if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.